# Table generation problem - Overfull \hbox

Tags: tables

I have a problem with table generation.

This is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\RequirePackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, top=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\hsize=.7\hsize\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{lightgray}}Y}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\columncolor{lightgray}}p{#1}}

\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C{5mm}@{}a*{3}{Y}@{}}
        %% table header
        \hline
        \rowcolor{lightgray}\multicolumn{2}{r@{}}{XXXXXX $\rightarrow$} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{The content of the word} \\
        \rowcolor{lightgray}\multicolumn{2}{l@{}}{$\downarrow$ XXXXXX} & XXXXX & XXXXXX & XXXXX \\ \hline
        %% body of table
        &XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXX  & XXXXX \\
        &XXXXX
         & XXXXX
         & XXXXX \par XXXXXXXXXX
         & XXXX, \par XXXX,\par XXXX/XXXX,\par XXXXX,\par XXXXXX, etc. \par \\
        \multirow{-3}{12mm}{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{\linewidth}{XXXXXXX}}} &XXXXXX XXXXX &  XXXXXXXX \par sequence
         & XXXXXX
         & XXXXXX, \par XXXXX, \par XXXXX \\     \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Table generates correctly and looks OK but a lot warnings like these are shown:

```
Overfull \hbox (18.35681pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 35--35
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 XXXXXXX 
 []


Overfull \hbox (19.91693pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 35--35
[]|[]| 
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in alignment at lines 35--35
[][][][][] 
 []
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you receive just warning ... they are caused by use of `RaggedRight` and no consistency in defining of the first column. try the following changed code of your table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{lightgray}}Y}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\columncolor{lightgray}}p{#1}}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}    
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C{12mm} a*{3}{Y}}
        %% table header
    \hline
    \rowcolor{lightgray}
\multicolumn{2}{r}{XXXXXX $\rightarrow$} 
                &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{The content of the word} \\
    \rowcolor{lightgray}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{$\downarrow$ XXXXXX} 
                & XXXXX     & XXXXXX    & XXXXX                 \\ 
    \hline
        %% body of table
    & XXXXX     & XXXXX     & XXXX  & XXXXX                     \\
    & XXXXX     & XXXXX     & XXXXX XXXXXXXXXX
                                    & XXXX, XXXX, 
                                      XXXX/XXXX, 
                                      XXXXX, XXXXXX, etc.       \\
\multirow{-4}{=}{\rotatebox{90}{XXXXXXX}} 
    & XXXXXX XXXXX 
                &  XXXXXXXX sequence 
                            & XXXXXX
                                    & XXXXXX, XXXXX, XXXXX      \\     
         \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

to my taste table isn't nice. i would use `caption` package for caption, omit coloring and use `booktabs` for horizontal lines.